# How to create a list of tuples C++

Tags: c++, list, boost, tuples

I am fairly new to c++, I dont really have any background in it.  I am tying to create a list of tuples, the first will be an int, the second will be a string.

```
  #include <string>
  #include <list>
  #include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
  ....
  list< tuple<int,string> > time;
```

And getting an error.  I want to be able to create a list, add entries that I can sort by the int, and have the string that describes, what the int was.

How would I create this list?

Comment: Dumb question:  Did you remember to add using namespace std / using namespace boost ?  What are the specific error messages you are getting?

Comment: Do you have a "using namespace boost;" in your code?  I guess you need a "using namespace std;" as well.

Comment: I think, you can use std::map<int, std::string> for that purpose. It will hold pairs `int-string`,automatically sorted by `int` values. [Here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) is the description.

Comment: You were correct, I was missing using namespace boost.  Haha, I got to get use to that, thank you!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

For a simple list use `std::vector` instead of `std::list`.

You probably just want something simple such as:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "boost/tuple/tuple.hpp"

using namespace std;
using boost::tuple;

typedef vector< tuple<int,string> > tuple_list;

int main(int arg, char* argv[]) {
    tuple_list tl;
    tl.push_back( tuple<int, string>(21,"Jim") );

    for (tuple_list::const_iterator i = tl.begin(); i != tl.end(); ++i) {
        cout << "Age: " << i->get<0>() << endl;
        cout << "Name: " << i->get<1>() << endl;
    }
}
```

`std::list` is actually an implementation of a doubly-linked list which you may not need.

Comment: Is there an easy way to sort it in this case by age?  Do I have to write my own sort function?

Answer (score 13):

The answers here are a bit outdated, and don't tell you how to sort the list.

Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) you can use the standard [`tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple), with a `vector` for example:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
// ...
vector<tuple<int, string>> data;
```

To add entries you can use the [`emplace_back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) method of `vector`.
Here's an example reading from the standard input:

```
#include <iostream>
// ...
int age;
string name;
while(cin >> age >> name) data.emplace_back(age, name);
```

To sort, it is sufficient to use the standard [`sort`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) function, since `int` is the first element of the tuple in our case, the default sorting order will sort the elements by `int`s first, then by `string`s:

```
#include <algorithm>
// ...
sort(data.begin(), data.end());
```

You can [retrieve values from a tuple](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) by index:

```
get<0>(data[i])
```

or by type:

```
get<int>(data[i])
```

I've put together a [full example that you can see live at ideone](http://ideone.com/EQC54I).

Answer (score 1):

Might not be relevant here, but if the "creation part" contains filling up the list with elements, Boost.Assign could be useful. You can do something like this:

```
#include <boost/assign/list_of.hpp>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    typedef boost::tuple<int, std::string> tuple;

    std::vector<tuple> v = boost::assign::tuple_list_of(1, "foo")(2, "bar");
}
```

Depending on your scenario ofcourse.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a side note:

The new C++ standard introduces variadic templates and with that also tuples. gcc and Visual Studio (at least) support these. So if it is possible for you (i.e. if all supported compilers support tuples which is already very likely) you could use this.

The only problem is, that some compilers still have tuple in the std::tr1 namespace and others already have it in the std namespace. Also sometimes you need to include  and sometimes . But you can configure your build system to define some macros which helps you to support several schemes. If you, for example only need to support Visual Studio 10 and/or a quite new gcc version you could do the following:

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>

std::list<std::tuple<int, string> > time;
```

For example with cmake you could generate a header file, which brings you support for all compilers, that support tuples (and with slightly more work even use boost as a fall back).

To do this, you would create something like a tuple.h.cmake file:

```
#if defined( __GNUC__ ) && (__GNUC__ * 100 + __GNUC_MINOR__ < 430)
# define GCC_OLDER_THAN_430 1
#endif

#if defined( _MSC_VER ) && (_MSC_VER < 1600 /* 2010 */)
# define MSC_OLDER_THAN_2010 1
#endif

#if defined( GCC_OLDER_THAN_430 )
# define TR1_IN_TR1_SUBDIRECTORY 1
#endif

#if defined( ZORBA_GCC_OLDER_THAN_430 ) || defined( ZORBA_MSC_OLDER_THAN_2010 )
# define TR1_NS_IS_STD_TR1 1
#endif

#ifdef TR1_NS_IS_STD_TR1
# define TR1_NS std::tr1
#else
# define TR1_NS std
#endif

#ifdef TR1_IN_TR1_SUBDIRECTORY
#  include <tr1/tuple>
#else
#  include <tuple>
#endif
```

Then, above example will look like follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <list>
#include "tuple.h"

std::list<TR1_NS::tuple<int, std::string> > time;
```

This should work on nearly all recent compilers.