# C++: List of tuples C++11/1y

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

A previous question and answer ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6482338/how-to-create-a-list-of-tuples-c)) showed that a list of tuples could be created by:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
using namespace std;
using boost::tuple;
typedef vector< tuple<int, int> > tuple_list;
```

While I don't get an error when running with C++98, C++1y (GCC/GNU on Ubuntu) gives:

```
error: template argument 1 is invalid
typedef vector< tuple<int, int> > tuple_list;
                                ^
error: template argument 2 is invalid
error: invalid type in declaration before ‘;’ token
typedef vector< tuple<int, int> > tuple_list;
                                            ^
```

Any idea what's going on? (If I could have commented on the other thread I would have, but awesome SO says my reputation is too low to comment!)

Comment: Do you pass the `-std=c++11` compiler flag to enable C++11? If yes, what's the compiler version?

Comment: @vsoftco The OP is using `boost::tuple` not the C++11 `std::tuple`

Comment: gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)

Comment: @vsoftco Your right.  I didn't see the `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @NathanOliver that's the issue, just tested it, although I have to say the error message is... let's just say weird.

Comment: The possible issues with name conflicts explode when you both `using namespace std;`.  There are many reasons not to do that.  Please stop doing that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is a name clash, you are `using boost::tuple` and also `namespace std;`, both of which bring `tuple` into the global scope, so you end up with two definitions of the same template. I don't understand why the compiler is not more explicit in diagnostic the error though...

Remove either `using boost::tuple;` or `using namespace std;` and qualify the corresponding names:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/tuple/tuple.hpp>
//using namespace std;
//using boost::tuple;
typedef std::vector< boost::tuple<int, int> > tuple_list;

int main()
{
    tuple_list foo;
}
```

I guess this is a prime example of why `using` is not too recommended ;)

Comment: `using` isn't "not too recommended". You need to know what you're potentially doing. Also, a different compiler might actually give you all the information you need: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4fab2e1cdbb35ea7

Comment: @rubenvb Yes, clang++ seems to be better at diagnostics. Personally I prefer `std::` before the standard names, although I am not super opiniated about it :)

Comment: @rubenvb `using namespace std;` (and in general, `using namespace` for any namespace you don't tightly control) **is** "not too recommended", especially at file scope

Comment: @Yakk that's true, but not what this answer says.